# How to set the option value through model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I need to have the value for the option in the following:

I have created my select as follows:

```
 <select id="fromSelectBox" multiple="multiple" >

          <% foreach (var item in Model.Projects) { %>
                   <option><%=Html.Encode(item.Text)%></option> 
                <%} 
            %>
            </select>
```

How do I set the value of the option using the value in the model which s item.ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
 <select id="fromSelectBox" multiple="multiple" >
```

```
      <% foreach (var item in Model.Projects) { %>
               <option value="<%=Html.Encode(Item.Text)%>"><%=Html.Encode(item.Text)%></option> 
            <%} 
        %>
        </select>
```

You can use any other property of item as well

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the HtmlHelper for drop down lists. The SelectList takes optional parameters for dataValueField and dataTextField.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("fromSelectBox", 
    new SelectList(Model.Projects, "ID", "Text"))
%>
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/archive/2009/03/27/asp-net-mvc-html-dropdownlist-and-selected-value.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use `<option value="<%=item.ID%>">`?